# How to recover from failed checkout and messed up current branch

Tags: git

I tried switching branches to a previous branch (P) but the command failed and now *some* of my sources are from the current branch (C) while the others are from the branch P that I hoped to switch to; and 'officially' I am still in branch C. How can I clear up the mess caused by the failed checkout and revert branch C to the last commit.

Comment: git reflog shows you the history of changes. Create branches off the shas you had before things got messed up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove all files, run

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

NOTE: Untracked files will be lost

Comment: Do you *really* mean that I should delete *all* my files before I run `get reset`? I have run the command (without deleting any files) but got the error message `fatal: cannot create directory at 'foo': Permission denied`

Comment: Now this looks like you have done something with root access.

Comment: What's even more unusual is that there is no directory foo on my filesystem.

Comment: Since git keeps the history of all versions of all your committed (!) files, it's save to mess with them. You can always checkout any version of any file. It's not that easy to lose committed data with git :)